# Laravel 5 Send email from Job

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

I have a controller that handles user registration and Job that actually register user. When i use:

```
Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ConfirmationEmail());
```

From controller it works just fine (it sends email, I'm using mailtrap) but when i add that same line at the end of my job email is not sent. I've imported Mail and ConfirmationMail  at the beginning on both files so it's not that. I would paste whole pages but don't see point in that since code works... Anyway my job queue is handled by Redis or database (tested both, same problem). Am I able to send email from queued job ?

Comment: Show logs, show errors show code or it did not happen.

Comment: Try setting your queue driver in your `.env` file to `sync, it will cause the job to execute along the request.

Comment: @tomirons When it's sync it works. But i want email to be sent in queue. Does that mean i cannot send emails from queued jobs ?

Comment: You can send the email straight to a queue with 5.3. Here's a link to the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#queueing-mail

Comment: @tomirons I'm 5.3 but for some reason it does not work...

Comment: Did you take that line of code out of the job? You can call it straight from the controller and send it to the queue that way.

Comment: @tomirons There is a problem about that, job is handling user registration so it needs to use data from input.

Comment: I just did a test and setup a test route, job, and mail class and it works. My queue driver is set to `sync`. It sounds like your queue driver configuration is a little messed up. If I were you, I'd read up on the documentation on queue drivers.

Comment: @tomirons Read previous comments. Sync works for me too, but sync is not really a queue since it execute at the same time as other code. My Job registers users, create record and send email. First 2 really do happen so i know my queue driver configuration works fine :)

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue would be then, I was able to get it working just fine in a matter of minutes.

Comment: @tomirons You tried putting your job to database or redis queue ?

Comment: Do you want me to test? I just use `sync` in development.

Comment: I just setup redis and it's till working. If you're in development you will have to run `php artisan queue:work` so it can process the jobs in the queue. Not sure if you've been doing that.